# Bootstrap sample making

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap and was practicing it. I have got a sample which I was trying to make using bootstrap and css but I am unable to do so. Please find image below.

[image: Image to made using bootstrap]

Please help me to let me know how I can make this using bootstrap

Comment: Show me your current code ?

Comment: I tried using bootstrap_glyphicons. as well as using angular mat-icons but I was not able to  get even 10% that's why asking here

Comment: See my anwser below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the same 100% but I only use Bootstrap, you can custom it to exactly what you want by add some CSS style.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  .border {
    border: 3px solid #000 !important;
  }
  .warning-icon {
    font-size: 150px;
  }
  .warning-text {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
</style>
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="text-center d-inline-block bg-warning p-1 rounded">
    <div class="border p-4 rounded">
      <h1 class="warning-icon"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></h1>
      <p class="warning-text font-weight-bold">OUT OF<br> SERVICE</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How I can add that warning triangle image in this?

Comment: Use the fontawesome like me or if you want to use image, do this simple by remove the line `<i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>` and add your image `<img src="YOUR_TRIANGLE_IMAGE.PNG">`

Comment: how I can make border with black color and put whole sample in center of page? as shown in sample

Comment: Check my anwser again, I think you should learn more HTML and CSS before practice

Comment: yes I will gi through html css once again . Just one more question ....this is working successfully but it is coming in small size in my html page. How can I make it in big size?>

Comment: Check my answer again, I will add `font-size` to CSS , you can change it to increase or decrease what you want.